# cloning disks with Lubuntu 12.04 lead to LVDS interface error

Tags: lubuntu, configuration, cloning

I want to ask about a problem I´m having when I want to clone an image of Linux Lubuntu 12.04 from one PC to another. Both systems are identical, hardware, memory and CF cards. 
The source system runs fine, and I´ve get the image with dd and Selfimage. when I download this image to the cloned system it boots ok, but when it should start the graphical interface, it freezes and send various messages on screen. I´m aware about the problem with eth0 and the 70-persistent-net file. Mi question is: Could it be a similar issue about graphical interface? Is there a file with hardware-related data that I could edit-delete, to match the new hardware?   Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

Lubuntu normally autodetects on boot, even if the hardware has not changed.

Are you sure you are booting to the right partition?
These days, the UUID is recorded in the boot files instead of e.g /dev/sda1. The UUID must match the new hard disk.